# Django - Calling function in ListView or model to change model bolean status

Tags: django, function, listview, button

I want to call a function - from a model or from a Listview that will change Order.isDone status - TRUE or FALSE after clicking the button in template.

Model.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    isDone = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Zrealizowane')
```

views.py:

```
class OrderListView (ListView):
  model = Order
  template_name = 'orders/orders_list.html'
  ordering = ['-orderDate']
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='page-home'),
    path('orders_list/', OrderListView.as_view(), name='page-orders-list'),
    path('completed_orders_list/', OrderCompletedListView.as_view(), name='page-completed-orders-list'),
    path('orders/order_create/', OrderCreateView.as_view(), name='page-order-create'),
    path('orders/<int:pk>/delete/', OrderDeleteView.as_view(), name='page-order-delete'),
]
```

template:

```
      <tbody>
        {% for order in object_list %}
          {% if order.isDone == False %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Szczegóły</button>
              <form action="{% url 'page-orders-list' order.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Finish order</button>
              <form>
              <a class="btn btn-danger adminButton" href="{% url 'page-order-delete' order.id %}">Usuń</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

What is the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using another view for this. You can use the `get` method in the view to change the status of the order. The in your HTML you would only need to use a link instead of a form.

So something like this:

views.py

```py
class OrderFinishView(RedirectView):
  success_url = None  # After finishing the order, where do you want to redirect the user?
  
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     order_id = self.kwargs['pk_order']  # pk_order must be in your URL
     order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=order_id)

     order.is_done = True
     order.save()

     return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='page-home'),
    path('orders_list/', OrderListView.as_view(), name='page-orders-list'),
    path('completed_orders_list/', OrderCompletedListView.as_view(), name='page-completed-orders-list'),
    path('orders/order_create/', OrderCreateView.as_view(), name='page-order-create'),
    path('orders/<int:pk>/delete/', OrderDeleteView.as_view(), name='page-order-delete'),
    path('orders/<int:pk_order>/finish', OrderFinishView.as_view(), name='page-order-finish'),
]
```

template

```html
      <tbody>
        {% for order in object_list %}
          {% if order.isDone == False %}
          <tr>
            <td>
                <a href={% url 'page-order-finish' order.id %}>Finish</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Another idea is to use an UpdateView to update your order with a PartialOrderForm which would only contain the `is_done` field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It basically works !!! :)  The bolean field in the model changes status after clicking the button, but I get url http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/19/finish and HTTP ERROR 410. It behaves as if success_url is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used the @vinkomlacic's solution, but i changed the return of get function:

```
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      order_id = self.kwargs['pk_order']  # pk_order must be in your URL
      order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=order_id)
      order.isDone = True
      order.save()
      return redirect(self.success_url)
```

Seems to be working properly now after setting success_url in class